Interpretation of dotted arrows and negative coefficient in PLS SEM - seminr package
I have obtained the following model. I am struggling to interpret the plot as I can't find an indication of how to interpret dotted lines and negative signs in front of beta and w coefficients.
enter image description here
Specifically:

Do the dotted arrows and negative beta denote a negative effect of a construct on another one? For instance, I should conclude that PLANT has a negative effect on bacteria and fungi and the latter on C while PLANT has a positive effect on C?

How should I interpret the dotted lines and negative sign in front of w concerning BAC_3 and FUN_2?
Thank you for any help you can provide


Cheers!
I tried pls sem model and bootstrapped the model
